# Calling fuctions from the .dll library using dynamic linking

Tags: c++, windows, dll, dynamic-linking, handle

Ok, so I', writting a C++ code for the MCP2221 converter. In order to use it I try to implement the .dll file. Namely **mcp2221_dll_m_dotnetv4_x86.dll** which can be downloaded from:
https://www.microchip.com/DevelopmentTools/ProductDetails/PartNo/ADM00559

I've tried to implement it but I still cannot call the functions and I cannot find the reason why.

I use the following code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
typedef string(WINAPI *MYPROC)();

int main()
{
    HINSTANCE hinstLib; 
    BOOL fFreeResult, fRunTimeLinkSuccess = FALSE;

    // Get a handle to the DLL module.
    char a;

    hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("mcp2221_dll_m_dotnetv4_x86.dll"));

    // If the handle is valid, try to get the function address.

    if (hinstLib != NULL)
    {
        cout << "LIB\tloaded" << endl;

        MYPROC ProcAdd = (MYPROC)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "M_Mcp2221_GetLibraryVersion");

        // If the function address is valid, call the function.

        if (NULL != ProcAdd)
        {
            cout << "FUNC\tloaded" << endl;
            string s= ProcAdd();
            fRunTimeLinkSuccess = TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "FUNC\tNOT loaded" << endl;
        }
        // Free the DLL module.

        fFreeResult = FreeLibrary(hinstLib);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "LIB\tNOT loaded" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The function is defined in the specification in the following way:

**String^ M_Mcp2221_GetLibraryVersion()**

Description: Returns the version number of the DLL
Returns: String containing the library version
Use Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() to determine the error code if the function fails.

I still get the **LIB     loaded
FUNC    NOT loaded** output.

Could anyone tell me what I keep doing wrong? Will appreciate a lot.

Comment: You are loading function `M_Mcp2221_GetLastError` and in the question you mention function `M_Mcp2221_GetLibraryVersion()`. They have different names

Comment: Sorry pasted wrong code here. Fixing it now.

Comment: From where did you get that function name?

Comment: From the pdf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you are using wrong dll and wrong function name.

You are trying to load function from dll for .Net-managed code - `MCP2221_DLL(v2.2.1)\managed\MCP2221DLL-M-dotNet4\x86\mcp2221_dll_m_dotnetv4_x86.dll`. With an utility that shows functions exported from dll, I haven't found any functions that are exported from this one.

Try using unmanaged dll `MCP2221_DLL(v2.2.1)\unmanaged\dll\mcp2221_dll_um_x86.dll`.
It has function `_Mcp2221_GetLibraryVersion@4`

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot @V. Kravchenko
After some research I've decided to change my assumpions and I'm trying to implement the unmanaged in the static way. However I get a mistake
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
**Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__Mcp2221_GetLastError@0 referenced in function _main**
I use  _mcp2221_dll_um.h_ file nad _mcp2221_dll_um_x86.lib_ file from the _/lib_ folder and I've followed the tutorial on adding the library so that I have proper linker and include settings.

Comment: @AlfąsNoblik It seems like now you have some problem with properly importing that .lib library in your project. Seems like it's not imported, as linker cannot find function which is in that lib. Check if you have written correct path to library to correct settings in your project settings.

Comment: I've checked it several times. Do you know any other reason it could produce such result?

Comment: **The code is fairly sillpe:**

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <mcp2221_dll_um.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 wchar_t xd;
 int stat = Mcp2221_GetLibraryVersion(&xd);
 int e = Mcp2221_GetLastError();
 //cout << xd << endl;
 return 0;
}

Comment: @AlfąsNoblik Simply including a header is not enough. To link the `lib`-library into your code, you should add it in project settings or use `#pragma comment(lib, "path\\to\\lib.lib")` in your source code. Including header just pastes header's contents inside your source file.

Comment: @V.Kravhcenko I've followed this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=or1dAmUO8k0
And I've added the paths and names in the VS settings in *Linker->general->Additional Library Directories*, *Linker->input->Additional Dependancies* and *C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories* in the way it was shown there.

Comment: I've also tried to use
**#pragma comment(lib, "C:\\...\\mcp2221_dll_um_x86.lib")** but the results are the same

Comment: Ok, I've read contents of that header file `mcp2221_dll_um.h`, and it says there `//for projects importing the .lib, use the MCP2221_LIB preprocessor definition`, so try inserting line `#define MCP2221_LIB` before line `#include "mcp2221_dll_um.h" `

Comment: Error LNK2038 mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1900' in 03 lib2.obj 
Error LNK2038 mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in 03 lib2.obj  
Error LNK2038 mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' 
Warning LNK4098 defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library  
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _swprintf_s referenced in function _Mcp2221_GetConnectedDevices@12 
Error LNK1120 1 unresolved externals

Comment: Just **#define MCP2221_LIB**?

Comment: @AlfąsNoblik Yeah, you've done that correctly. Linker found that function and that lib. There are two more problems with that lib though. The problem now is, you are using different compiler version then compiler version used for that library. The error says you are using `_MSC_VER = 1900` which is Visual Studio 2015 and the library uses `_MSC_VER = 1800` which is Visual Studio 2013. (or vice versa, I'm not sure). The second problem is the usage of C++ standard library. The version of c++ standard library used in that lib is release lib - `/MT` and you are using debug dll `/MTDd`

Comment: So what could I do?
btw I've checked the dynamic linking and it works correctly.

Comment: You could fix those problems by configuring your project or use dynamic linking if that works for you.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. After all I use dynamic linking though I would prefer the static way. You have no idea how much time did it take for me to communicate with that converter. **Really thanks a lot** ;)